# How to replace two continuous inverted commas "" in a Java String?

Tags: java

Using Java, I want to go through the lines of a text and replace all `""` symbols with a `null` entity reference.

Here is a sample string

```
String str = "asdsadas:\"\":asdasdASD:\"\":aSdasdcsC";
```

Result wanted is

```
String resStr = "asdsadas:null:asdasdASD:null:aSdasdcsC"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, as that isn't valid Java code to start with.

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: `String resStr= str.replaceAll("","null")`;  ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Nope... you need some coffee.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm `escaping` from you now  :P

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ nope, this did not work

Comment: @sri  - Jordi Castilla is your friend :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your string is not correct. In `java` you need to scape `QUOTES`:

```
String str = "asdsadas:\"\":asdasdASD:\"\":aSdasdcsC";
```

After, you need to escape quotes also to replace them:

```
String resStr= str.replaceAll("\"\"","null");
System.out.println(resStr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
asdsadas:null:asdasdASD:null:aSdasdcsC
```

---

OR if you need `QUOTES` in the output:

```
String str = "\"asdsadas:\"\":asdasdASD:\"\":aSdasdcsC\"";
String resStr= str.replaceAll("\"\"","null");
System.out.println(resStr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"asdsadas:null:asdasdASD:null:aSdasdcsC"
```